# expanding rows using data.table gives error about recycling

Tags: r, data.table

I need to expand a data table with 1 row per person to one with variable rows per person.  I know the exact number of rows for each person.  I keep running into an error about not recycling the vector I am supplying (see below).

I can't seem to figure out how to turn this feature off temporarily, or how to work around it.

example:

```
x <- data.table(a = 1:5, b = letters[1:5])
x[, c := 1:a, by = b]
```

Gives me the error below

`` Error in `[.data.table`(x, , `:=`(c, 1:a), by = b) :  Supplied 2 items to be assigned to group 2 of size 1 in column 'c'. The RHS length must either be 1 (single values are ok) or match the LHS length exactly. If you wish to 'recycle' the RHS please use rep() explicitly to make this intent clear to readers of your code. ``

It seems that other functions than `rep()` should be allowed.  But even when I wrap this in `rep()` it doesn't seem to help.

`x[, c := rep(1:a, times = 1), by = b]`

gives the same error.

For what it is worth, I would like 1 copy of row 1, 2 copies from row 2, 3 copies of row 3, etc.  In the actual use case, the number of rows to be added (represented by column a) is based on a calculation of the expected rows for a person (represented by column b).

Is there a data.table friendly way of doing this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We cannot assign (`:=`) when the output column is of different length than the original one.  Instead, keep it in a `list`

```
x[, .(c = 1:a), by = b][x, on = .(b)]
```

---

Or if there are only two columns and have a 1-1 relationship

```
x[, .(c = seq(a)), .(b, a)]
```

Comment: that works.  thank you so much!  also just doing by = .(b, a) works to since there is a 1:1 relationship between b and a